# Декодировка JPG не может найти соответсвие в таблице хаффмана

Tags: jpeg, huffman

Пытаюсь декодировать JPG файл, вся заголовочная часть правильно прочитана. Во время считывания самого тела фотографии (SOS, 0xFFDA) в некоторый момент функция по нахождению соответсвия в таблице хаффмана уходит в бесконечный цикл. Если посмотреть файл в hex редакторе то на месте ошибки можно найти следующюю последовательность байт:

```
7F FF 00 61
```

FF 00 => FF

```
7F FF 61
```

что в двоичном коде

```
0111 1111 1111 1111 0110
```

первый бит уже использован прошлым MCU, теперь идет 15 единиц подряд а затем ноль. В соответсвующей таблице хаффмана максимальный код это 8 единиц подряд и один ноль.
Я сделал вывод что байт 7F был просто заполнен единицами до конца. Но ведь это не конец файла. Как мне определить когда нужно пропускать байт, а когда нет?

Comment: можно ли дублиовать вопрос на английскую версию сайта?

Comment: можно ли дублировать вопрос на английскую версию сайта? [Даже нужно](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7543/%D0%AF%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85-stackoverflow)

Comment: @Anamnian, можно задавать вопросы только раз в 90 минут. Надо было наоборот.

Comment: Я ответил на свой вопрос [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51650653/jpg-huffman-decode-stucks/51667095#51667095)

Comment: Хорошо что у вас получилось найти решение. А если вы еще и перенесете ответ на этот сайт, по крайней мере я поставлю вам "за".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка появилась намного раньше чем проявился ее симптом. 
Проблема была связана с алгоритмом по декодированию AC коэффициента. Я изменил условия цикла `do-while` с  `(index != 63)` на `(index <= 63)`. Символ конца блока EOB попадал как раз на 64 элемент матрицы MCU, условие не срабатывало и этот символ попадал в начало следующего MCU. Алгоритм брал с [этой документации](https://www.w3.org/Graphics/JPEG/itu-t81.pdf) (страница 106)
Еще в программе [jpegsnoop](https://www.impulseadventure.com/photo/jpeg-snoop.html) при выборе опции `detailed decode` когда EOB попадает на конец блока можно заметить надпись `EOB64` вместо `EOB`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]